# Recursively loop through objects of object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function to go through an object and return items based off an ID. I can get the first part of this to work, but I'm having a hard time trying to get this function in a recursive manner and could use a fresh set of eyes. The code is below. When you run the snippet, you get an array of 6 items which for the first iteration is what I want, but how can I call my function with the proper parameters to get the nested items? My end goal is to have the all the objects starting with 'Cstm', nested ones too, to be added to the tablesAndValues array. I was trying to model my code after this: [Get all key values from multi level nested array JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363138/get-all-key-values-from-multi-level-nested-array-javascript), but this deals with an array of objects and not an object of objects. Any hint or tips I can get are very appreciated.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xov49jLs/

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition": {
      "child_welfare_placement_value": ""
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics": {
      "school_grade": "family setting",
      "school_grade_code": ""
    },
    "Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds": [
      {
        "med_name": "med1",
        "dosage": "10mg",
        "frequency": "daily"
      },
      {
        "med_name": "med2",
        "dosage": "20mg",
        "frequency": "daily"
      }
    ],
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use": {
      "dimension1_comment": "dimension 1 - tab1",
      "Textbox1": "text - tab1"
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note": {
      "prior_auth_no_comm": "auth no - tab2"
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan": {
      "cca_cs_dhs_details": "details - tab2"
    },
    "container": {
      "Cstm_PF_Name": {
        "first_name": "same text for textbox - footer",
        "last_name": "second textbox - footer"
      },
      "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics": {
        "new_field": "mapped demo - footer"
      },
      "grid2": [
        {
          "Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis": {
            "diagnosis_label": "knee",
            "diagnosis_group_code": "leg"
          }
        },
        {
          "Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis": {
            "diagnosis_label": "ankle",
            "diagnosis_group_code": "leg"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "submit": true
  }
};

function getNamesAndValues(data, id) {
  const tablesAndValues = [],
        res = data;
 
  Object.entries(res).map(([key, value]) => {
    const newKey = key.split('_')[0].toLowerCase();
    
    // console.log(newKey) // -> 'cstm'
    
    if (newKey === id) {
      tablesAndValues.push({
        table: key,
        values: value
      });
    } else {
      // I can log value and key and see what I want to push 
      // to the tablesAndValues array, but I can't seem to get 
      // how to push the nested items.
      
      // console.log(value);
      // console.log(key);
      
      // getNamesAndValues(value, key)
    }
  });
  
  return tablesAndValues;
}

console.log(getNamesAndValues(response.data, 'cstm'));
```

Comment: In your else clause you’re probably going to want to concatenate results from the recursive call, something like `return [...tablesAndValues, ...getNamesAndValues(value, key)]`

Comment: @rayhatfield Thanks for the response, Ray. I'll try that out.

Comment: Updated my comment to also spread the result of the recursive call.

Comment: I tried that updated code but no dice there. Still only 6 items in there. I like this approach though so I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the result with a single push, one can pass the result table to the function when called recursively, but default it to an empty table on the first call. I've also changed `.map` to `.forEach` since the return value is not used:

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition": {
      "child_welfare_placement_value": ""
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics": {
      "school_grade": "family setting",
      "school_grade_code": ""
    },
    "Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds": [
      {
        "med_name": "med1",
        "dosage": "10mg",
        "frequency": "daily"
      },
      {
        "med_name": "med2",
        "dosage": "20mg",
        "frequency": "daily"
      }
    ],
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use": {
      "dimension1_comment": "dimension 1 - tab1",
      "Textbox1": "text - tab1"
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note": {
      "prior_auth_no_comm": "auth no - tab2"
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan": {
      "cca_cs_dhs_details": "details - tab2"
    },
    "container": {
      "Cstm_PF_Name": {
        "first_name": "same text for textbox - footer",
        "last_name": "second textbox - footer"
      },
      "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics": {
        "new_field": "mapped demo - footer"
      },
      "grid2": [
        {
          "Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis": {
            "diagnosis_label": "knee",
            "diagnosis_group_code": "leg"
          }
        },
        {
          "Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis": {
            "diagnosis_label": "ankle",
            "diagnosis_group_code": "leg"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "submit": true
  }
};

function getNamesAndValues(data, id, tablesAndValues = []) {
  const res = data;
 
  Object.entries(res).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const newKey = key.split('_')[0].toLowerCase();
    if (newKey === id) {
      tablesAndValues.push({
        table: key,
        values: value
      });
    } else {
        getNamesAndValues( value, id, tablesAndValues);    }
  });
    return tablesAndValues;
}

console.log(getNamesAndValues(response.data, 'cstm'));
```

Comment: There it is. Thanks for this answer also. Using that third param inside the `else` is interesting and I need to read up on what is going on there. Big thanks again for this.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call push to tablesAndValues inside the else statement with the rest operator and pass the value and id as parameters

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition": {
      "child_welfare_placement_value": ""
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics": {
      "school_grade": "family setting",
      "school_grade_code": ""
    },
    "Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds": [
      {
        "med_name": "med1",
        "dosage": "10mg",
        "frequency": "daily"
      },
      {
        "med_name": "med2",
        "dosage": "20mg",
        "frequency": "daily"
      }
    ],
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use": {
      "dimension1_comment": "dimension 1 - tab1",
      "Textbox1": "text - tab1"
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note": {
      "prior_auth_no_comm": "auth no - tab2"
    },
    "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan": {
      "cca_cs_dhs_details": "details - tab2"
    },
    "container": {
      "Cstm_PF_Name": {
        "first_name": "same text for textbox - footer",
        "last_name": "second textbox - footer"
      },
      "Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics": {
        "new_field": "mapped demo - footer"
      },
      "grid2": [
        {
          "Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis": {
            "diagnosis_label": "knee",
            "diagnosis_group_code": "leg"
          }
        },
        {
          "Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis": {
            "diagnosis_label": "ankle",
            "diagnosis_group_code": "leg"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "submit": true
  }
};

function getNamesAndValues(data, id) {
  const tablesAndValues = [],
        res = data;
 
  Object.entries(res).map(([key, value]) => {
    const newKey = key.split('_')[0].toLowerCase();
    
    // console.log(newKey) // -> 'cstm'
    
    if (newKey === id) {
      tablesAndValues.push({
        table: key,
        values: value
      });
    } else {
      // I can log value and key and see what I want to push 
      // to the tablesAndValues array, but I can't seem to get 
      // how to push the nested items.
      
      // console.log(value);
      // console.log(key);
      
      tablesAndValues.push(...getNamesAndValues(value, id))
    }
  });
  
  return tablesAndValues;
}

console.log(getNamesAndValues(response.data, 'cstm'));
```

Or in shorter way

```
function getNamesAndValues2(data, id) {
    return Object.entries(data).reduce((arr, [key, value]) => {
        arr.push(
            ...(key.split('_')[0].toLowerCase() === id ? [{ table: key, values: value }] : getNamesAndValues(value, id))
        );
        return arr
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: This was cool. I wasn't aware I could spread the `getNamesAndValues()` function. Ideally I was trying to do it with only one `.push()`, but maybe that's not possible. Either way though thanks for this answer.

Comment: I did some change with ternary and reduce for fun, you can see at getNamesAndValues2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version. I call the main function recursively if the value is either an array or an object. Also passing in the current state of the tallying array each time.

```
function getNamesAndValues(data, id, tablesAndValues = []) {
  const res = data;
 
  Object.entries(res).map(([key, value]) => {
    const newKey = key.split('_')[0].toLowerCase();
    const item = res[key];

    if (newKey === id) {
      tablesAndValues.push({
        table: key,
        values: value
      });
    }
    
    if(Array.isArray(item)) {
        return item.map(el => getNamesAndValues(el, id, tablesAndValues));
    }

    if(typeof item === 'object') {
        return getNamesAndValues(item, id, tablesAndValues);
    }

  })

  return tablesAndValues;
}

console.log(getNamesAndValues(response.data, 'cstm'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using generators -

```js
const keySearch = (t = [], q = "") =>
  filter(t, ([ k, _ ]) => String(k).startsWith(q))

const r = 
  Array.from
    ( keySearch(response, "Cstm")
    , ([ table, values ]) =>
        ({ table, values })
    )

console.log(r)
```

```js
[
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition',
    values: { child_welfare_placement_value: '' }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics',
    values: { school_grade: 'family setting', school_grade_code: '' }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds',
    values: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use',
    values: {
      dimension1_comment: 'dimension 1 - tab1',
      Textbox1: 'text - tab1'
    }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note',
    values: { prior_auth_no_comm: 'auth no - tab2' }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan',
    values: { cca_cs_dhs_details: 'details - tab2' }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_Name',
    values: {
      first_name: 'same text for textbox - footer',
      last_name: 'second textbox - footer'
    }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics',
    values: { new_field: 'mapped demo - footer' }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis',
    values: { diagnosis_label: 'knee', diagnosis_group_code: 'leg' }
  },
  {
    table: 'Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis',
    values: { diagnosis_label: 'ankle', diagnosis_group_code: 'leg' }
  }
]
```

Above, `keySearch` is simply a specialisation of `filter` -

```js
function* filter (t = [], test = v => v)
{ for (const v of traverse(t)){
    if (test(v))
      yield v
  }
}
```

Which is a specialisation of `traverse` -

```js
function* traverse (t = {})
{ if (Object(t) === t)
    for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries(t))
      ( yield [ k, v ]
      , yield* traverse(v)
      )
}
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
function* traverse (t = {})
{ if (Object(t) === t)
    for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries(t))
      ( yield [ k, v ]
      , yield* traverse(v)
      )
}

function* filter (t = [], test = v => v)
{ for (const v of traverse(t)){
    if (test(v))
      yield v
  }
}

const keySearch = (t = [], q = "") =>
  filter(t, ([ k, _ ]) => String(k).startsWith(q))

const response =
  {"data":{"Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition":{"child_welfare_placement_value":""},"Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics":{"school_grade":"family setting","school_grade_code":""},"Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds":[{"med_name":"med1","dosage":"10mg","frequency":"daily"},{"med_name":"med2","dosage":"20mg","frequency":"daily"}],"Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use":{"dimension1_comment":"dimension 1 - tab1","Textbox1":"text - tab1"},"Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note":{"prior_auth_no_comm":"auth no - tab2"},"Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan":{"cca_cs_dhs_details":"details - tab2"},"container":{"Cstm_PF_Name":{"first_name":"same text for textbox - footer","last_name":"second textbox - footer"},"Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics":{"new_field":"mapped demo - footer"},"grid2":[{"Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis":{"diagnosis_label":"knee","diagnosis_group_code":"leg"}},{"Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis":{"diagnosis_label":"ankle","diagnosis_group_code":"leg"}}]},"submit":true}}

const result = 
  Array.from
    ( keySearch(response, "Cstm")
    , ([ table, values ]) =>
        ({ table, values })
    )

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably elegant recursive answer might look like this:

```js
const getNamesAndValues = (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj)
        .flatMap (([k, v]) => [
          ... (k .toLowerCase () .startsWith ('cstm') ? [{table: k, value: v}] : []), 
          ... getNamesAndValues (v)
        ])
    : []

const response = {data: {Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition: {child_welfare_placement_value: ""}, Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics: {school_grade: "family setting", school_grade_code: ""}, Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds: [{med_name: "med1", dosage: "10mg", frequency: "daily"}, {med_name: "med2", dosage: "20mg", frequency: "daily"}], Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use: {dimension1_comment: "dimension 1 - tab1", Textbox1: "text - tab1"}, Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note: {prior_auth_no_comm: "auth no - tab2"}, Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan: {cca_cs_dhs_details: "details - tab2"}, container: {Cstm_PF_Name: {first_name: "same text for textbox - footer", last_name: "second textbox - footer"}, Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics: {new_field: "mapped demo - footer"}, grid2: [{Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis: {diagnosis_label: "knee", diagnosis_group_code: "leg"}}, {Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis: {diagnosis_label: "ankle", diagnosis_group_code: "leg"}}]}, submit: true}}

console .log (getNamesAndValues (response))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But this is not as simple as I would like.  This code mixes the searching for matches and the test used in that searching together with the formatting of the output.  It means that it is a custom function that is both more complex to understand and less reusable than I would like.

I would prefer to use some reusable functions, separating out three feature of this functionality.  So, while the following involves more lines of code, I think it makes more sense:

```js
const findAllDeep = (pred) => (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj)
        .flatMap (([k, v]) => [
          ... (pred (k, v) ? [[k, v]] : []), 
          ... findAllDeep (pred) (v)
        ])
    : []

const makeSimpleObject = (name1, name2) => ([k, v]) => 
 ({[name1]: k, [name2]: v})

const makeSimpleObjects = (name1, name2) => (xs) => 
  xs .map (makeSimpleObject (name1, name2))

const cstmTest = k => 
  k .toLowerCase () .startsWith ('cstm')

const getNamesAndValues = (obj) => 
  makeSimpleObjects ('table', 'values') (findAllDeep (cstmTest) (obj))

const response = {data: {Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Disposition: {child_welfare_placement_value: ""}, Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics: {school_grade: "family setting", school_grade_code: ""}, Cstm_Precert_Medical_Current_Meds: [{med_name: "med1", dosage: "10mg", frequency: "daily"}, {med_name: "med2", dosage: "20mg", frequency: "daily"}], Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Substance_Use: {dimension1_comment: "dimension 1 - tab1", Textbox1: "text - tab1"}, Cstm_PF_ADG_Discharge_Note: {prior_auth_no_comm: "auth no - tab2"}, Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Clinical_Plan: {cca_cs_dhs_details: "details - tab2"}, container: {Cstm_PF_Name: {first_name: "same text for textbox - footer", last_name: "second textbox - footer"}, Cstm_PF_ADG_URT_Demographics: {new_field: "mapped demo - footer"}, grid2: [{Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis: {diagnosis_label: "knee", diagnosis_group_code: "leg"}}, {Cstm_PF_ADG_COMP_Diagnosis: {diagnosis_label: "ankle", diagnosis_group_code: "leg"}}]}, submit: true}}

console .log (findAllDeep (cstmTest) (response))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

These are all helper functions of varying degree of reusability:

- **`makeSimpleObject`** takes two key names, say `'foo'`, and `'bar'` and returns a function which takes a two-element array, say `[10, 20]` and returns an object matching those up, like `{foo: 10, bar: 20}`
- **`makeSimpleObjects`** does the same thing for an array of two-element arrays:  `makeSimpleObjects('foo', 'bar')([[8, 6], [7, 5], [30, 9]]) //=> [{foo: 8, bar: 6}, {foo: 7, bar: 5}, {foo: 30, bar: 9}]`.
- **`cstmTest`** is a simple predicate to test whether a key begins (case-insensitively) with `"cstm"`.
- and **`findAllDeep`** takes a predicate and returns a function which takes an object and returns an array of two-element arrays, holding the keys/value pairs for any items which match the predicate.  (The predicate is supplied both the key and the value; in the current case we only need the key, but it seems sensible for the function to take either.

Our main function, **`getNamesAndValues`**,  uses `findAllDeep (cstmTest)` to find the matching values and then `makeSimpleObjects ('table', 'values')` to convert the result to the final format.

Note that `findAllDeep`, `makeSimpleObject`, and `makeSimpleObjects` are all functions likely to be useful elsewhere.  The customization here is only in `cstmTest` and in the short definition for `getNamesAndValues`.  I would count that as a win.